# Number of Github repositories at a certain time in the past

Tags: github, google-bigquery, github-api

Is it possible to search github repositories according to a keyword at a certain time in the past using [githubarchive.com](https://www.githubarchive.org/)?

Github API has [search repositories](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories) function, which I would like to use to find list of repositories, but at a certain time in the past.

Example:

If I search keyword `hippopotamus` I get result list of 14 repositories.

I would like to search keyword `hippopotamus` for date `16 Dec 2013`. I should get list of 4 repositories, because at that time only 4 repositories exist with keyword `hippopotamus`.

Is this possible with githubarchive?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Are you trying to write a query to determine a count of projects that were *created* in a certain time frame with a particular name? Or that were *modified* in a certain time frame? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard I want to get [list of repositories](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories) that exist in a time range. GitHub has search function, where you type a keyword and you get list of repositories. I would like to achieve this search functionality, but in a specific time range. I checked *Github API* and *Github Archive*, but I have no idea to achieve this with Github Archive.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want - can you give us a specific search you would run?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I am really sorry, I edited the question. I meant **at a certain time in the past** instead of **in a time range**.

Comment: i don't think there's a direct way to get this (some field changes are not reflected on GitHub Archive). I see you posted a similar question for Stack Overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572529/how-to-retrieve-number-of-tags-in-specific-time-range). Wondering what's the big picture...

Comment: @Matt I am little curious. If you don't mind me asking, why do you want to use GitHub archive for this ? As I see it, it is fairly straightforward with GitHub API (V3) (i.e. `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=hippopotamus+created:<2013-12-17` ). If I am not mistaken, with GitHub archive you will need to individually query every year database 2013,2012,2011 individually and check.  Further, if there are  any repo, which went inactive before 2/12/2011, it would not be included in GitHub archive.

Comment: @PoonachaMedapa Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I didn't know I can define `created` argument in search query. I wonder how can I define this search query `repositories?q=hippopotamus+created:<2013-12-17` in SQL format to run it with GitHub archive. I am not experienced in databases.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I would like to see how some repositories popularity evolve over time.